# Newline characters not showing up in proc file

Tags: c, linux, vim, linux-kernel, kernel

So I'm writing a linux kernel module that involves writing to a proc file. Unfortunately something is going wrong with the newline character. If I open it with vim, it shows as "num^@num^@num^@". If I cat it, it says "numnumnum". It should go to a new line at the end of each "num".

My code for writing each entry to the proc file admittedly seems kind of hacky.

```
    bufSize = snprintf(str,0,"%lu\n",var);
    str = (char*)kmalloc(bufSize*sizeof(char),GFP_KERNEL);
    snprintf(str,bufSize,"%lu\n",var);
    memcpy(msg+msglen,str,bufSize);
    msglen+=(bufSize);
    kfree(str);
```

I don't know how long the string will be, so the first snprintf gets the length needed for the buffer. The buffer is initialized, then snprintf is called again. The string is then copied to msg, which contains the data for the proc file. The pointer is incremented by the length of the existing message.

```
    int procfile_read(char *buffer, char **buffer_location, off_t offset, int
    buffer_length, int *eof, void *data) {

    int ret;

    printk(KERN_INFO "procfile_read (/proc/%s) called\n", PROCFS_NAME);

    if (offset > 0) {
    /* we have finished to read, return 0 */
    ret  = 0;
    } else {
     /* fill the buffer, return the buffer size */
    memcpy(buffer, msg, msglen);
    ret = msglen;
    }

    return ret;
```

This is pretty much copied and pasted from a tutorial.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffer size is too small

```
bufSize = snprintf(str,0,"%lu\n",var);
//                            + 1
str = (char*)kmalloc((bufSize + 1)*sizeof(char),GFP_KERNEL);
//                   + 1
snprintf(str,bufSize + 1,"%lu\n",var);
//                            + 1
memcpy(msg+msglen,str,bufSize + 1);
// no + 1 here
// Note that msglen is the string length.  Add 1 for the size needed.
msglen+=(bufSize);
kfree(str);
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I still don't quite get why you don't add 1 on the increment but this works!

Comment: `msglen` is the _length_ without the trailing `\0`.  It accumulates the total _length_ and is then the offset for the `memcpy()`.  That offset does not want the +1.

Comment: The original "num^@" (which is "num\0") came up because `snprintf(str,bufSize,"%lu\n",var);` was 1 too small putting `\0` in the `bufSize-1` position, which was copied via `memcpy()`.